# Opening .MAP file extention?

Tags: software-recommendations

I have a number of files in a folder listed below.

- BDBR70FL.FRQ
- BDBR70FL.FRW
- BDBR70FL.MAP

which software is suitable to open them.

Comment: Can you clarify more, from where did you bring those files ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a Google search on "frq frw map" I was able to quickly find that these appear to be files distributed by [The DHS Program (Demographic and Health Surveys)](http://www.dhsprogram.com/data/File-Types-and-Names.cfm):

> .MAP, .FRQ and .FRW files may be opened using an ASCII text editor,
>   such as Notepad.

The same page describes them as being:

```
File layout or codebook (.MAP)
Unweighted frequency distribution (.FRQ)
Weighted frequency distribution (.FRW)
```